# How to speed up the process of downloading and storing of audio files?

Tags: android

I have to download and store a large number of audio(**.mp3**) and images for the first time user launches the application.
The size of individual image and audio file is small and is roughly same for both. The number of images is double as that of audio. So, to download images, I'm using [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) which is working flawlessly and is very fast. As for the audio files I'm using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

while((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
     output.write(data, 0, count);
}

output.flush();
```

The problem is that the above process of downloading and storing audio files is taking very long to complete as compared to process of downloading images on the same network speed. So, why is this process taking so long and is there any way to speed up this process maybe on par with volley speed?

Comment: Why aren't you using Volley for mp3 too?

Comment: `byte data[] = new byte[1024];`. I would use a much bigger buffer.

Comment: @greenapps can i use volley for mp3 too??? How can I do that?? Can you provide me with some example. I was going to ask this but i thought volley can only used for json responses and image fetching.

Comment: Well i don't know. It is something that downloads files. Is Volley not able to download to file system? Strange omission. Otherwise use DownLoadManager.

Comment: @greenapps Yeah, Download Manager was going to be my next option(after doing some research). You suggested using a bigger buffer. Any suggestion for the value?

Comment: Didn't you test that already? 100KB or 1MB i would try. Then check how much `count` becomes. You will soon see if the buffer size has effect.

Comment: Well I increased the buffer size and there is a significant effect on the speed.
Thanks for the suggestion. I think I am going to go with this. Thank You.

Comment: You forgot to tell which size you use now.

Comment: oh sorry...i use 4096 now!!

Answer (score 0):

Using multithreading you might be get some improvement.

You can create list of runnable threads and iterate each thread and start all threads one by one.

Give some bunch of file to each thread.

Do not forgot to use join() method to all threads to each other.

Hope this helps you

Comment: won't this method consume a lot of bandwidth and battery on the device??

Comment: No, it will not consume more bandwidth. Say you wants to download 20 mb file. if you create 1 thread to download then it will consume 20 mb. If you start 2 thread then each thread consume 10MB. But yes it will take more battery.

Comment: I tried it but it is not helping me much :-( The results are improved but not that much. Anyways, Thank you for your answer.